# My android App stop playing sound on button tap after some time

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

*Hello there, i have just created a basic android app which plays different musics on button tap..
The app just worked fine for the first couple of seconds but when i just keep on tapping and tapping , at some point it stops playing the music and just crashed...
I am unable to figure out what the problem is ..Please help me make it work..
Thanks.
Here is my code :-*

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

public void PlayMusic(View view)
{
int ID = view.getId();
String NameID = view.getResources().getResourceEntryName(ID);
int sound= getResources().getIdentifier(NameID,"raw","com.example.pickachu.mypatatap");
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,sound);
mediaPlayer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

Comment: share error stacktrace.

Comment: Play the MediaPlayer in a foreground service. Google Android service.

Comment: Actually, i am beginner can u please explain your point..And how can i do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sound is not playing after multiple taps because you must be getting `IllegalStateException` because you are not [releasing the Mediaplayer object](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release()) and [Mediaplayer Lifecycles](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram) are not managed properly when you tap multiple times.
You can use [`setOnCompletionListener(MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener listener)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener)) to release `mediaPlayer` after completion of sound as:

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,sound);
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.reset();
                mp.release();
                mediaplayer = null;
            }
        });
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Thanks bro it worked for me...But i have a doubt , why don,t the garbage collector  release the object memory here...

Answer (score 0):

**pass uri instead string**

```
mediaPlayer= MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/Music/music.mp3"));
mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mpintro.start();
```

Comment: I recently noticed  that it actually stopped playing sound exactly after 14th tap on the buttons.

Comment: okay, can you please add whole code for tap button and play sound