# When using MediaPlayer, sometimes it does not sound

Tags: android

for recording file output, I use MediaPlayer. 
usually, When I button clicked, start media file.

but, sometime not sound play.

```
/MediaPlayer: mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
W/MediaPlayer-JNI: MediaPlayer finalized without being released
```

at first I think  before the voice file is finished, when clicked button occur  this problem.

but even if I press the button repeatedly, sometime not sound play.

source.

```
player = new MediaPlayer();
player.reset();
player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

try {
    player.reset();
    AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor = 
    getApplicationContext().getResource().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.sound);
    player.setDataSource(assetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), 
    assetFileDescriptor.getStartOffset(), assetFileDescriptor.getLength());
    player.prepare();
    player.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
   @Override
   public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
      if (player != null) {
          player.stop();
          player.release();
      }
   }
});
```

How to fix sometimes not sound play when i button clicked?

thanks.

Comment: Just put mp.release(); after mp.reset();

Comment: refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534509/my-android-app-stop-playing-sound-on-button-tap-after-some-time

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to call `MediaPlayer.release()` if it will be used again, as calling `reset()` will release all the memory & codecs that are in use.

init:

```
player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
   @Override
   public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
       mediaPlayer.reset();
   }
});
```

Handling button clicks:

```
void onButtonClicked() {
    player.reset();
    AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor = 
    getApplicationContext().getResource().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.sound);
    player.setDataSource(assetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), 
    assetFileDescriptor.getStartOffset(), assetFileDescriptor.getLength());
    player.prepare();
    player.start();
}
```